# Can selected fields be imported from one table to another in mysql (phpmyadmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there a way to add selected fields from one table structure to another table structure with mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to copy part of one table structure to another without the actual data.  What I found will work is to export the table structure from which I want to copy columns and from that make the SQL to add the desired fields to the destination table.  So the SQL export give me the data I need for an ALTER statement to add the new fields.

```
ALTERTABLE`events`ADD`start_date` DATE NOTNULL DEFAULT'9999-00-00',
 ADD`end_date` DATE NOTNULL ,
 ADD`start_time` INT NOTNULL DEFAULT'00',
 ADD`end_time` INT NOTNULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement as follows:
ur source table is test1
u require some desired columns from test2 to add up to test1

One of the solution is:
The following will create a new table with ur desired result:

```
CREATE TABLE test3 (PRIMARY KEY (id))
Select test1.*,test2.value,...desired values from test2
from test1 inner join test2 on (test1.id = test2.rel_id)
```

Comment: The column must already exist in the source table for this.  I am looking for a way to alter a table structure by appending to that structure fields from another table.

Comment: can u illustrate? I can help u.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use a `SELECT` statement inside an `INSERT` one. If they have a different structure you can adapt the results from the SELECT using AS to change each of the field's names.
For example:

```
INSERT INTO table2(field2_1,field2_2) SELECT field1_1 AS field2_1, field1_2 AS field2_2 FROM table1;
```